# Excel: Horizontal Axis Labels as Text

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I cannot for the life of me have the horizontal axss labels show as TEXT on my line graph.

See the horizontal axis labels are showing as numbers (0, 5, 10, 15, etc)

[image: Graph]

Although the data has "Q3 2011", "Q4 2011", etc.

[image: Data]

The data source even shows such values :

[image]

The axis options are as follows:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Expanding "Labels" doesn't reveal anything useful:

[image: Labels]

Comment: Don't use the Number section, look in "Labels"?

Comment: @bioschaf: I have added a screenshot of "Labels" - nothing of use there.

Comment: It looks like your graph is a scatter plot, not a line plot. "Logarithmic scale" is not an option for line plots.